# Unity Navigation NavMeshAgent

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, navigation

So this worked fine before updating Unity, but after i updated i keep getting this two error

UnityEngine.AI.NavMeshAgent.Resume()' is obsolete: `Set isStopped to false instead'

UnityEngine.AI.NavMeshAgent.Stop()' is obsolete: `Set isStopped to true instead'

This is my code

```
public class Navigation : Interaction
{
public float RelaxDistance = 5;

private NavMeshAgent agent;
private Vector3 target = Vector3.zero;
private bool selected = false;
private bool isActive = false;

public override void DeSelect()
{
    selected = false;
}

public override void Select()
{
    selected = true;
}

public void SendToTarget()
{
    agent.SetDestination(target);
    agent.Resume();
    isActive = true;
}

void Start()
{
    agent = GetComponent<NavMeshAgent>();
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    if (selected && Input.GetMouseButtonDown(1))
    {


        var tempTarget = RtsManager.Current.ScreenPointToMapPosition(Input.mousePosition);

        if (tempTarget.HasValue)
        {
            target = tempTarget.Value;
            SendToTarget();
        }

    }

    if (isActive && Vector3.Distance(target, transform.position) < RelaxDistance)
    {
        agent.Stop();
        isActive = false;
    }

}}
```

My Prefabs have have a NavMeshAgent  And i rebaked the terrain.. I just need to be point in the right Direction or a hint

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do what the errors say and change agent.Resume() to agent.isStopped = false and agent.Stop() to agent.isStopped = true.

Comment: What you mean it doesn't work? You still receive errors?

Comment: Aright i worked fine, some fucking reason i needed to restart unity